# Fix "This channel is already in use" on Tinkerboard (Python)

Tags: python, tinker

I am trying to port an example for a Mifare RFID Card reader from Raspberry to the Tinkerboard. The program works, and the RFID Cards are accepted.

However, the RESET functionality is not working. There is a warning that says that the channel 22 is already in use.

I isolated the code that is responsible for the warning and have put it in a separate script. The warning still appears. I checked whether i used the right GPIO Pin, and i also tried other PINS, i always get the same message: "This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings."

```
import ASUS.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(22, 1)
```

---

EDIT

Even with try / except the warning still appears

```
import ASUS.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    GPIO.output(22, 1)

except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
    print("Keyboard interrupt")

except:
    print("some error") 

finally:
    print("clean up") 
    GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

Comment: Try this, the tinker board python api is based on the RPi api https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55143/gpio-warning-channel-already-in-use

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help. I still get the warning...